# How to use virtualbox sharefolder of linux virtualmachine?

Tags: permissions, virtualbox

OS:Ubuntu 16.04
virtualbox:5.1
I created a centos and a win7 virtualmachine with addtional function. In win7 virtualmachine, sharefolder can be write and read, but in centos, 'no permission'.
somebody told me`sudo usermod -a -G vboxsf yourusernanme`, but `cat /etc/group` ,actually without `vboxsf` group.
what's the solution to use virtualbox sharefolder of linux virtualmachine??

Comment: Did you add the `guest additions` and what do you mean by __no permission__?

Comment: Did you add the guest additions in the guest machine (centos)?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In the Centos VM, open a `terminal` and type:

```
sudo adduser your_username vboxsf
```

then logout/login, or reboot the VM.

Your shared folders should work now.